# Send values from one application form to another application form in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a c# 2 application.
I want to send user name HQAdmin.exe

I use this code.

```
 Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"\HQAdmin.exe", "" + strUserGroupID + " " + strUserID + " " + strUserName + " " + strPDateDMY + " " + strPDateMDY + "");
```

How can get that values with in HQAdmin application?

I have setting variable, string username 
I use is code get user name

```
Properties.Settings.Default.username ;
```

that code doesn't work, how can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're showing in that example, is passing *command-line arguments* to the process when it is started.  How you handle those arguments in the child process depends on what language it's written in.  In most languages, the command-line arguments are passed as arguments to the `main` function.

C#

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string username = "default";

    if (args.Length >= 1) {
        username = args[0];
}
```

See also: [Main() and Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/acy3edy3.aspx)

I'm not a VB.net programmer, but it appears you can use [`My.Application.CommandLineArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2d603cy.aspx) there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the arguments like this:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

foreach(string arg in args){
     //do something
}
```

Edit: Sorry, this is for C#, but I think you get the idea.